# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Projects#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading

I would like to upload multiple photos with carrierwave. Here's what I have:

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
   end

   version :small do
     process resize_to_fit: [200, 200]
   end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader 
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @project) do |f| %>
<div id="new_project_form">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %><br />
  <%= f.label :caption %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :caption %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @project.name %></h1>
<%= image_tag @project.images_urls.to_s %>
<%= @project.caption %>

<%= link_to "edit", edit_project_path(@project) %>
```

I get this error when I upload a project with multiple images: 
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Projects#show

The asset "[\"/uploads/project/images/5/%5B%22Screenshot_20181028-145315.png%22%5D\"]" is not present in the asset pipeline.

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`image_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) is an assets helper, its designed to display images from the assets pipeline - not to create generic `<img>` tags.

You should instead use the regular [tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) helper :

```
<%= tag :img, src: @project.images_urls.to_s %>
```

Comment: That actually didn't fix things but I still upvoted it as that is good advice. Thanks!